# Error while entering Meteor app in the terminal

Tags: meteor, frontend, meteorite, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to startup a meteor app but it show this error:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Meteor 0.9.2.2 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `accounts-entry`:
error: no such package: 'spark'
client/views/accountButtons/accountButtons.html:5: Unexpected closing template tag
...rapLinks}}<li>{{/if}}         <a class='p...
                    ^
error: no such package: 'domutils'
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, at line 5 of your `accountButtons.html` - file, there is a `{{/if}}` which should not be there. Just remove it.

Comment: That doesn't work, even if I delete that {{/if}} it show this message => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `accounts-entry`:
error: no such package: 'spark'
error: no such package: 'domutils'

Comment: Then that means that meteor is looking for packages spark and domutils and can't find them. Make sure that you either have them installed or remove them from the packages file (which you find at .meteor/packages)

Comment: That doesn't work either, when I remove the accounts-entry package and after that I run meteor, the terminal shows me more errors: => Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
error: no such package: 'spin'
error: no such package: 'momentjs'
error: no such package: 'iron-router-progress'
error: no such package: 'zurb-foundation'
error: no such package: 'accounts-entry'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Comment: Apparently, your packages file is screwed up. Try running "meteor update"

Comment: I also tried that, maybe it's better to start a new app

Comment: Perhaps that's the best option then.